# How do I set cookies using Python urlopen?

Tags: python, cookies, redirect, urlopen, http-error

I am trying to fetch an html site using Python urlopen.
I am getting this error:

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop

The code:

```
from urllib2 import Request
request = Request(url)
response = urlopen(request)
```

I understand that the server redirects to another URL and that it is looking for a cookie.
How do I set the cookie it is looking for so I can read the html?

Comment: You have a web page that redirects to another web page which redirects to the first one (loop).

Comment: yeah i know that, i am looking for a way to get around this

Comment: Drop the link in a [Redirect Checker](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/).  See what it comes up with.  And does this work in a browser?  What about a browser running in private/incognito mode with data cleared?

Comment: i checked with Redirect Checker - it redirects to himself. it does work in a browser because the browser supports cookies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example from [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#examples), adjusted to your code:

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = opener.open(request)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Was messing around with Selenium and Spynner, but really it seems that I can use urllib2 for everything, even with cookies and form data and redirects and session ids that expire.