# Script fails randomly due to urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302

Tags: python, http, cookies, web-scraping, urllib

I have a strange problem i've been trying to 'google-out' for several hours.
I've tried also solutions from similar topics on **stack** but still wiht no positive result:

> [How do I set cookies using Python urlopen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113652/how-do-i-set-cookies-using-python-urlopen)
>   [Handling rss redirects with Python/urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926023/handling-rss-redirects-with-python-urllib2)

So the case is that i want to download whole set of articles form some webpage. Its sub-links with proper content differ with just one number, so I loop for whole range ( 1 to 400 000 ) and write html's to files. Whats importatnt here is this webpage need the cookies to be re-send in order to get to proper url, and after a lecture of  [How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage) i have this done.

But some times my script returns error:

> response = meth(req, response)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 468, in http_response
>      'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>   ....
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 553, in http_error_302 self.inf_msg + msg, headers, fp)
>   **urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.**
>   **The last 30x error message was:**
>   **Found**

This problem is hard to reproduce because script generally works fine but it happens randomly after a few thousands of 'for loops'.

Here is curl ouptut from server:
`$ curl -I "http://my.url/"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2012 10:14:13 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3

Set-Cookie: Kuuxk=ae7s3isu2cEshhijte4nb1clk5; path=/

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Pragma: no-cache

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Some folks suggested to use mechanize or try to catch exception but i have no clue how to do this, others said that error is caused by wrong cookie handling but i tried also to get and send cookies 'manually' using urllib2 and `add_header('cookie', cookie)` with similar result.
I wonder if my `for` loop and mabey to short sleep might cause script to fail some times..
Anwyay - **any** help appreciated.

edit:
In case this might work - how to catch the exception and try ignore it ?

edit:

Solved by simply ignoring this error. No everything goes fine.
I used

```
    try:  
        #here open url  
    except any_HTTPError:  
        pass
```

On each time i use url.open instruction.

TO BE CLOSED.

Comment: What do you mean by 'TO BE CLOSED.'?

Comment: Then you can answer your own question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another solution:
HTTP status code 302 means `Found redirection` (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

For example:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/`

You can grab the `Location` header and try fetching this url.

There are 8 redirection status codes (301-308). You can for `Location` header if 301 <= status code <= 308.